# How can I create a django model instance with deferred fields without hitting the database?

Tags: python, django

Say I have some fields of a row of a django Model that I know exists in the database, but don't have them encapsulated in a Model instance. Is there any easy way for me to wrap them in a Model instance, without doing an extra DB query, and end with an instance that has those fields populated but all other fields deferred?

So say I have model:

```
from django.db.models import CharField, IntegerField, Model

class Person(Model):
    name = CharField(max_length=20)
    age = IntegerField(default=10)
```

And I have a dictionary:

```
raw_person = {'id': 3, 'name': 'Alice'}
```

And I want to end with a model instance *without another database query*:

```
alice = Model(id=3, name='Alice', age=<deferred>)
```

such that doing:

```
alice.name
```

is immediate, but

```
alice.age
```

would require another query to the database to get the age for `alice`.

Obviously (?) I can't just do:

```
alice = Model(id=3, name='Alice')
```

Because that would set `age = 10` since that's the default on the field, but that is probably not Alice's actual age.

Any ideas?

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers my real problem that prompted me to ask this question I have solved in a different way, but I've had a couple of instances where a tool to do this might have been useful so I'm curious to know if there is a solution.

Comment: ok, fair enough - and thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assign `django.db.models.DEFERRED` to the fields you want to defer, i.e.:

```
alice = Model(id=3, name='Alice', age=django.db.models.DEFERRED)
```

Note that this only works on instantiation, you can't assign `DEFFERED` after creating the model.

You obviously can't defer the primary key.